# Prestashop - Controller Not Found in admin

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a simple module, but I'm unable to successfully make the admin controller work.

This is the directory structure for my module:
[image]

And this is the AdminPaymentsController.php file:

```
<?php

class AdminPaymentsController extends  ModuleAdminController {

}
```

I created a tab on my module installation using this function:

```
public function installTab($parent, $class_name, $name) {
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->id_parent = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName($parent);
    $tab->name = array();

    foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
        $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']]  = $name;
    }

    $tab->class_name = $class_name;
    $this->module = $this->name;
    $tab->active = 1;

    return $tab->add();
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
    if (!$this->installTab('AdminCatalog', 'AdminPayments', 'Payments Management')) return false;
```

The tab seems to be installed correctly:

[image]

But when I open it, it show an error message:

[image]

`http://dev.prestashop.com/admin123asdf/index.php?controller=AdminPayments&token=52dbfa9a1a6c3935fd3cbb1276bcbedb`

Why is this happening? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller file name should be `AdminPayments.php`.

And change this line: `$this->module = $this->name;` for this one: `$tab->module = $this->name;`

Good luck.

Comment: This works perfectly. Dozen of my modules tells me ;) Fix the other bug I comment. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the `installTab` function. It should be:

```
$tab->module = $this->name;
```

Instead of

```
$this->module = $this->name;
```